# Visual Studio 2015 encapsulate field adds to wrong line

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In VS2015 when I encapsulate field

```
private AdminAccountDetailsDC _Profile;
```

I get this result

```
public AdminAccountDetailsDC Profile
{
    get
    {
        return _Profile;
    }

    set
    {
        _Profile = value;
    }
}
```

But it's added to random line, just in the middle of file. Comparing to VS2012 - result was added right after private field. Is it possible to correct that and my property is added right below field?

Comment: there is no "right" and "wrong" here; perhaps it is trying to add it after the last field, on the basis of "fields, then properties", or similar? unrelated and subjective, but IMO you'd be better off making this an auto-prop rather than an explicitly encapsulated field... i.e. `public AdminAccountDetailsDC Profile {get;set;}`

Comment: @MarcGravell this example was added for simplicity, it means I use at least setter to add there some code (MVVM). Also it adds property not after last field, it can add property between methods where fields are not present anymore and I consider it as "wrong"